# How to update username and email filed in Mikepenz drawer android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-drawer

```
// Create the AccountHeader

    AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)

            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(uname).withEmail(email).withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person1))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();
```

so here i want to update name and email filed. those data will fetch from firebase and want to update in name, email fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

[image]

Update profile with identifier.